# Samsung printer m2070 no working on ubuntu

Tags: usb, printing

I have installed the drivers for printer samsung m2070, it is connected via usb, it is added to the list, but it does not work, how to find a solution, I am a new user of ubuntu
Tanks

Comment: Any error messages? Can you print the "test page" from the printer icon?

Comment: i can't print a test page

Comment: no erorr message

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260672/edit) and add how you installed the driver. If you installed using the terminal please copy and paste all output including errors directly from the terminal to the question. Please add all new information by editing your question.

Comment: Have you added your printer via `http://localhost:631`? That's the interface to CUPS, the Common Unix Printing System.

Comment: the problem is the driver, there is no specific driver for samung m2070, I downloaded it from the samsung website driver for linux but it doesn't work

Comment: I have Samsung M2070W and I made it working under Ubuntu. Nowadays, I download drivers from **HP** (it's correct, I think HP acquired Samsung's printer division) https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2070-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16450377/model/16450387  The file is named: uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz. I installed it as root. (tar -zxvf uld... to unpack, cd uld.., make, make install). Then I go to CUPS in browser: localhost:631, delete automatically installed printer and add new manually.

Comment: During the installation in CUPS you should see a list of suggested drivers, which was extended after installing from ULD. I don't remember the exact name, but it was first (or second) position. I installed M2070W via USB as well as via WiFi (separate installations in CUPS).

Comment: there is no samsung m2070 in the list

Comment: solved, with the help of a ppk file that I found in the uld folder,

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 installs ippusbxd and, by default, starts the daemon. The USB interface to the printer becomes unavailable to the Samsung software. cups-browsed should auto-setup a driverless print queue that can be seen by lpstat -l -e and printed to.

If you do not want this to happen, and are prepared to lose the benefit of IPP-over-USB, then execute `apt purge ippusbxd`

Comment: The actual claimed solution is interesting considering there don't seem  any to be any pkk files in uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz.